# Connect Azure VMs with the same names to Log Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-diagnostics, azure-monitoring, azure-log-analytics

It is possible to connect Azure VM to Log Analytics via Microsoft Monitoring Agent virtual machine extension (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-azure-vm-extension). But the data received in Log Analytics has nothing to say about the subscription or the resource group the VM belongs to. This means that if I have two VMs with the same names in two different resource groups then in Log Analytics there is no way to differentiate between them. So, is there a workaround for this? Is it possible to enrich the data collected by Microsoft Monitoring Agent?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to enrich the data collected by Microsoft Monitoring Agent at the moment.

Someone alredy created a request:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/267889-log-analytics/suggestions/17005000-multi-tenancy-collect-azure-health-logs-from-diff